# How to Intercept a navigating event and get the data being posted

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, browser

I am using webbrowser to complete a checkout process. I need to intercept a submit action, get the data being submitted and resend the request with the post data with user agent injected in the browser.

But when I intercept the navigation, I only get the URI. I dont get the data being posted. How to get the POST DATA ?

```
public ICommand NavigatingCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand<NavigatingEventArgs>(OnNavigatingCommandReceived); }
    }

    private async void OnNavigatingCommandReceived(NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
      e.cancel = true;// first time request is intercepted and cancelled.
      var url = e.Uri.OriginalString; 
    }
```